# no article for countable noun followed by ``as''

Tags: articles

The sentence below seems missing something but as a non-native speaker it is hard for me to tell what is wrong with it.

> Finally, we selected a single representative RPG from each cluster, according to universality and deviance, to serve **as marker gene.**

Should "as marker gene" be "as the marker gene", "as a marker gene", or "as marker genes"?

Personally I want to express "marker gene" as a general concept so "as the marker gene" does not fit. "as marker gene" sounds most natural to me but it violates the grammatical rule of article + countable noun. "as marker genes" sounds also OK but only a single RPG was selected so "genes" seems wired. Which one is be better?

Comment: Nope, to serve as **a** gene marker. Except for newspaper-type titles, English requires a/or plural s/es OR a the. [Example: We chose a boy to be the goalkeeper.] "as" has nothing to do with it here.

Comment: @Lambie, I see nothing wrong with a boy being chosen to be goalkeeper, born to be King, or elected Prime Minister.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, but born to be a king is not the same.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't *need* an article because it is a unique *title* for something within the specific context. It seems that the article would be optional. It could even be correct with the indefinite article.

A comparable noun might be 'manager'. It is a countable noun, and can be a person's title - there are many people working as managers, and an organisation may have many managers within its structure. An individual could rightly say "*I act as manager for this department*"; however, it would be just as correct to say they are "*the manager*".

Comment: to serve as **a** marker gene. He acts as a manager for this department.

Comment: @Lambie those would only be correct if there were the possibility for multiple managers/marker genes within the confines of the context. For example, in most card games someone acts as *a* dealer. Within the context of a single game, that person is *the* dealer.

Comment: Here, an a is definitely needed. It is not a title. A single representative to serve as a gene marker. is standard.

Comment: @Lambie To be clear, are you saying the original quote is ungrammatical? And if so, is that because it feels ungrammatical, or because of a rule about articles?

Comment: @Lambie sadly you are incorrect. It is not "standard". Example - you're preparing to play a game of Association Football. Which of these sounds most idiomatic to you: "*You be goalkeeper*", or "*you be **a** goalkeeper*"?

Comment: Actually, you can say that someone acts as a dealer in a card game. It depends on the statement. To be the goalkeeper, to be a goalkeeper and to be goalkeeper are all usable depending on context. For me, here it is being used as a gene marker.

Comment: @Lambie sadly you are incorrect. There can be only one dealer in any game of cards so if the context is a specific game then the indefinite article would be inappropriate. Likewise, a football player may be "a goalkeeper", but if you said they were "a goalkeeper for Manchester United" then questions would be raised - is he a *past* goalkeeper? How many goalkeepers does the team have?? Yes, you're quite wrong.

Comment: I am not mistaken. The choices depend on **context**.  He is a goalkeeper for Manchester United, not for Tottenham Hotspurs.

Comment: @Lambie Yes, sadly, you are very much mistaken and your comments are becoming increasingly non sequitur. Also, it is 'Hotspur'. There is only one of them.